# Selecting photo from cam roll on ipad requires pop over controller error

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, uipopovercontroller, ios-universal-app

Im converting an an iPhone app to universal.

One of my functions requires picking a photo from camera roll from a button in a table view controller.  Im getting an error saying I need to use a pop over controller to do this.

`On iPad, UIImagePickerController must be presented via UIPopoverController'`

As this is built in code (im picking this up from another developer) could I get some advice on on doing this properly in code.

```
UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
imagePicker.delegate = self;
imagePicker.allowsEditing = YES;

[self presentModalViewController:imagePicker animated:YES];
```

What ive tried so far:

```
UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
imagePicker.delegate = self;
imagePicker.allowsEditing = YES;
////////
imagePicker.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext; 
////////
[self presentModalViewController:imagePicker animated:YES];
```

and

```
UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
imagePicker.delegate = self;
imagePicker.allowsEditing = YES;
////////
self.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;
////////
[self presentModalViewController:imagePicker animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a UIPopoverController.

```
UIPopoverController *popoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc]
initWithContentViewController:imagePicker];

popoverController.delegate = self;

[popoverController 
     presentPopoverFromRect:sender
     permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp
     animated:YES];
```

Here's an example:
http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Example_iOS_4_iPad_Camera_and_UIImagePickerController_Application_(Xcode_4)

Comment: Thanks for answer, unfortunately that dosent work for me, and also I need it to work on iPhone as well as iPad.  The link seems says "There is no page titled "An_Example_iOS_4_iPad_Camera_and_UIImagePickerController_Application_(Xcode_4"."